# Asure SignalR service hub breakpoint not hit from Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, signalr-2

I am prototyping calling a SignalR hub from front end code and a Azure Function (through Azure SignalR Service). I have it working at a basic level but the breakpoint in my hub is not being hit when called from the Azure Function.

Hub (complete code, no other methods):

```cs
    public class JobHub : Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessage(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message);
        }
```

Azure Function:

```cs
    public static class SignalRPrototypeFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("GarageUpdated")]
        public static async Task<ActionResult> Run
        (
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalR(HubName = "JobHub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
            ILogger log)
        {

            await signalRMessages.AddAsync
            (
                new SignalRMessage()
                {
                    Target = "broadcastMessage",
                    Arguments = new[] { "Azure", "Hello" }
                }
            );

            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
```

When I connect to my Azure SignalR Service from the browser I have a button press that does `connection.send('broadcastMessage', "username", "message");` which hits 
a breakpoint on `Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message);` of the hub.

Doing the call from the function **does push the message through to the front end** (so it must be going through this line?) **but the breakpoint doesn't get hit.**

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I am thinking about this wrong. From a bit more debugging it seems that the code isn't going via the hub in my web app? Which means any logic I have there for client -> client interaction would need to be duplicated prior to the call in my function?

Comment: Also do any breakpoints work? If you create another function is same app with a log statement will it hit?

Comment: Yes, breakpoint is hit from a front end request but not the function. I am now thinking the function code and the hub operate independently to do the same thing.